# how to check list of vertex is connected each other in gremlin

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, gremlin, gremlin-server

I have the list of vertex and I want to check is these vertexes are connected to each other or not. If these are connected then return the edges or return an empty list.

LIST of Vertex = `[v[10], v[11], v[12], v[13], v[14], v[15], v[16], v[17], v[18], v[19], v[20]]`

if Yes, then return  `v[10]-created-v[11]`
if No, Then return `[]`

Comment: I believe your question was answered here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/Rhg2g_BPUzg

Comment: That was not working @KelvinLawrence

Comment: Please provide a gremlin script that creates a sample of your data that we can test against. That's the best way to ask questions about gremlin.